# How to see the Exception thrown by the Blackberry Application

Tags: blackberry

I am new to Blackberry Development. In my app it is throwing an Exception,it is showing on simulator. I want to know how can I see this exception in detail like 'Logcat' in Android.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you asking to see the stacktrace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

try
{

```
//write code here;
```

}

catch(final Exception e)

{

```
  UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
                public void run()
                {
                        Dialog.alert("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);//if you want to close the application;
                } 
});
```

}

Enough;
If you have doubts come on StackOverFlow chat room name "**Life for Blackberry**" to clarify Your and our doubts

Answer (score 1):

try{
     ......
     .....
}
catch(Exception ce){
     System.out.println(ce.getMessage());
}

if you are using ECLIPSE just run the application in DEBUG mode....
Then check  for whichever exception occured in console pane.